# Simplify Regular Expression, Automata Theory

Tags: regex, regular-language, automata

I recently needed to figure out the regular expression for the language
{w **|** |w| is odd and w starts and ends with symbol b} over the alphabet {a,b}.

I figured out a solution being

```
b(ab+bb+aaab+aabb+abab+abbb+bbbb+bbab+babb+baab)*
```

The solution is very long, so I was hoping someone could tell me a way this can be simplified,

Comment: Your "solution" is wrong. Catches `baa` which isn't in your language.  Anyway, if you have any more regexes to find, feel free to call for my attention in comment. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks, that happened to be a typo actually. It was meant to be "bb"

Comment: Anyway, upvote the correct answer, Just to be fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `b|(b(a|b)((a|b)(a|b))*b)`
The language you describe can produce just b, and that's captured by the first branch, and this is the only size 1 string it can produce. Then it can produce size 3,5,7,... strings. Those are captured by the second branch. The b at the start and end are self-explanatory. And those account for 2 characters. The middle bit is the classic language `{w | |w| is odd}` over `{a,b}`.

A more powerful syntax would allow something like `b((a|b)((a|b)^2)*b)?`, which is more compact, but equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one:

```
(b(a|b)(aa|ab|ba|bb)*b)|b
```